# How to setup iTerm “Visor” option like TotalTerminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, iterm2

I configured my iTerm using this tutorial: http://technosophos.com/content/configure-iterm2-act-visor

But I have few problems with it, for example when I am in fullscreen mode and I press `CMD + Tab` to switch to Chrome and then I want to go back to iterm also using `CMD + Tab` nothing happens so I have to use my HotKey.

Second related thing is when I have opened iterm window and press in dockbar on iterm icon it opens new instance of iterm but I would like to activate last iterm window if it is any.

Is possible to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 2):

CMD + Tab to the terminal, but before you release CMD, press and hold the Option key (also called the "alt"-key).

That is the OSX shortcut to unhide windows when you switch to them. (You can normally hide windows to the task bar with CMD + M)

Answer (score 0):

> Second related thing is when I have opened iterm window and press in
>   dockbar on iterm icon it opens new instance of iterm but I would like
>   to activate last iterm window if it is any.

Go to Preferences > Advanced > Hotkey and set to `Yes` this setting
`If the only window is a hotkey window, then clicking the dock icon shows or hides it`